# Can we use a same .STL file for both visual and collision while building URDF?

Tags: ros, rviz, urdf, stl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have .STL files for my robot model. Can we use the same .STL files for both visual representation and collision representation  while building URDF?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368562/can-we-use-a-same-.stl-file-for-both-visual-and-collision-while-building-urdf?/) by [srujan](https://answers.ros.org/users/51644/srujan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2020-12-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Can we use the same .STL files for both visual representation and collision representation while building URDF?

Yes, you can.

But you probably don't want to.

The `collision` geometry is typically used by motion planners (such as MoveIt) to perform collision checks, and in most cases, performance of that step is inversely proportional to the fidelity of the `collision` geometry you've supplied.

So in general I would recommend to only use the same meshes for both if you are OK with reduced performance or the `visual` mesh is low fidelity already.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-12-29**:
Note: whether planning performance really is slower with high fidelity meshes for `collision` of course depends on the planning software used. Some will allow you to approximate collision geometry using convex hulls/shapes, or perhaps even capsules.

As MoveIt is often used with URDFs and you're asking this on ROS Answers, I've provided the main rationale for why we have separate `visual` and `collision` elements.